# Typescript 'types are incompatible'?

Tags: typescript, types

I am building the Typesafe formbuilder, it should produce a chain of excecutable functions that look like this: `FormBuilder.Entity(Pair(DefaultStudent, {}), q =>
    q.Select('name', 'gender')
    .Children('courses', q => q.Select('code'))`

It all works right know, but I get a type error on the `q.select('code')` part stating that type entity is not compatible with other types.

This the code used to generate the form :

```
interface FormSelector<T, U> {
    entity: Pair<T, U> 
    Select: <K extends keyof T>(this: FormSelector<T, U>, ...properties: K[]) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U>
    Children: <K extends Filter<T, Array<any>>, P extends keyof ArrayType<T[K]>>(
        child: K,
        q: (_: FormSelector<ArrayType<T[K]>, U>) => FormSelector<Omit<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>, Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>>
    ) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, U & {[key in K]: Array<Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>>}>
}

interface FormBuilder {
    Entity: <T, U, K extends keyof T>(entity: Pair<T, U>, q: (_: FormSelector<T, U>) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U>) => Renderer<Pick<T, K> & U>
}

export let FormBuilder: FormBuilder = ({
    Entity: function <T, U, K extends keyof T>(entity: Pair<T, U>, q: (_: FormSelector<T, U>) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U>): Renderer<Pick<T, K> & U> {
        let x = q(FormSelector(entity)).entity.Second
        return { data: x }
    }
})

let FormSelector = <T, U>(e: Pair<T, U>): FormSelector<T, U> => ({
    entity: e,
    Select: function <K extends keyof T>(this: FormSelector<T, U>, ...properties: K[]): FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U> {
        return null!
    },
    Children: function <K extends Filter<T, Array<any>>, P extends keyof ArrayType<T[K]>>(
        child: K,
        q: (_: FormSelector<ArrayType<T[K]>, U>) => FormSelector<Omit<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>, Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>>
    ): FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, U & {[key in K]: Array<Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>>}> {
        return null!
    }
})


// This will be responsible for rendering the form, can be pas to a react component
interface Renderer<T> {
    data: T
}
```

Here are the sample models I used:

```
type Student = {
    id: number
    name: string
    paid: boolean
    gender: 'm' | 'v'
    courses: Course[]
}

type Course = {
    name: string
    code: string
    studypoint: number
}

const DefaultStudent: Student = {
    id: 1,
    gender: "m",
    name: '',
    paid: false, 
    courses: []
}
```

When I change the type of entity in `FormSelector` from `Pair<T, U>` to `any` then it compiles, but then I lose the typesafety. Any can explain the erro I am getting or having an idea what it is causing this?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAp2FAKgTwA4QA8WANMgKoB8yA3gFDKPIBimAzmAFzKkNMDKEBAHsQAE27k6AXzp1QkWIhTpMAeQJQ4YYKLbEyVWn0YBbOHm7EAShDYBXADZhDth88oAKMAAtgbblUoAwpKMhhuTwB9biwASmQAXmosNycXZABzSJiKBOSKNOd86iCbO3TXCo8TZHM8ABkIGC5kcvcwL19-QIxg0lDwnNiSniKwUbLU6oyqWvrrYEyfVsJyca6-ALQ+kKoybORoyVH1mcndgbOOyhk5CAAPPGEoMGQREA5kAEkxCHBgGAcA04KYAEZiOBJNpYLyjTwPEZJagPe5PF5vD5fILQvZeGDsVoDNhCUQSPK9TB45FHehMFiE7gEqAcEi1QQfckkzls+n1Jn2EAIHSiGHjKo3bxbSn9QxhZARI65eI06YdA7DPI067pOIy9qVQozSh0+lMKAQMD2KAgHaYTwwKX+AB0rBZEwOTrYzo5ZLicVq0l5THqTRaAqFIttBo8Xv1V3liuOPFGat18fFoWMZvNluttu63vqDrIv3+OiBIPBkM8-sDwbMFkWy1aMEFwt0traOtjhfjco1SpO2vGertsqNN2zOeQFqtNuQhedxbLAMroIhcFrBwD9Nk0gDdEez1ei-wKkucuhQVwBGpADJxxpoNpO-oE2iT28gQRkABBKAtBwW8iFhaEsGQR5IHENh-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-ux2pBdZ4WprFsAQcMZBHxoAqIuC21ee4TnCABoHCEVu9lb5mXsekW5ZAGxRhpQFnTAAIXsGm-igJj7LXBaYUMMh1qSvHtqKngvDmoFFv2ZAmaHA6joqj68Q1zPJs+77dYGP6ZflkGDdCUZbHEaBKOt4Hi9B0I7iPdFTwqt5vb9gPoG4Lv-c01DGM8GaQ4rMO20jTtw4oSPcZg2PdoT0Pk-lNPk29tnTrlXOt4Ln7G9Lm3G4rgXuGrwO67Lk+weoUf6Q75AHmhBnPE3rWoE8ROcH9XTQ59Uk4hKa5nnLaGgyBIRgDgNwZ+sg9wyEPI-d+Wd2a4gTF-VeY5kH52pAUEetRv7cAgPTNmEYOyikIFHBGi9iqbB6BnPeeJzqXWurdYA91kCPWen3IWKDtaFz1mga+kcm5GHviA-MBknCOAAIT1lqJDAOMMyFRjaFQmOSNKIDEthjLGOMNoLwJqpO2oEyZeGAYwamtNOH03pOvXI2Ds4mJ5o7SuNJHEix1rbeCXN7bSzQHLG2ziHaq1uPSLBvCcFeMPphQ2xscCm04bFOCaN67eKApLfxstKAu2DvSOckiQDSLkfAg8cg6C2SwFsZAAB3GmPEwQoAtGwZ4nxgBggqgqHqMNA6gEyGpMaZAEAY2QI05AeA4CwRksgKEFpECYmEKYVp5Z3ZDWUMgC+td+h31qJA6BPAW62TsuIBUWgLI1JeKFOQHl2JWj+OAaEo9gDkiKeCaAtRzLGWcmAKAfTagTOedwMEwhhAVQxrUTIm1e7IAAOSmBhcgAAPrC3CMLagiGtCSbYNFMUQCei3G5OKWQoEYqPT53AOC-JAJkdFwg-gUp+X8+kHB7BiHwMIBQ2F7BvN8m7LEbwAAizQ4DpH4Hc8s3AxWsvLI82ogLkAAEZ6aQprlAUypgTL03JbCmF9MAXkngI5YhyBaW4u2Pit2-ce5QGdMc8enggieCFfAUV4rwBkBoAeMgDNkS1AZgAlBngYWfJhdZFizEADqblbTtkWXNal-F-DIEcKAFAgJan1KyMAfCMzeKQUAi8WorFnSKOhv8INGLiVsF1anGk-q2ZBpDXWOgCRbKJAKJsi0wQaAXWdLIIAA)

Comment: Could you provide all the types used in the code? Ideally a playground link..

Comment: I see, what I forget give me a second

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have added a playground link

Comment: The code is based on this project https://github.com/Steven24K/Type-Safe-LINQ/blob/master/src/core/Table.ts in Children is basicly the Include method

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Forgot another few types, know everything is complete ;)

Comment: Oof, is this really a [mcve]?  There's so much going on in there; if you whittle it down to the smallest code that reproduces your issue, there's a much better chance someone will be able to make a recommendation (or you'll figure it out yourself, which would presumably be an even better outcome).   Read about [ask] for more tips about how to get a question in a maximally-answerable state.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments there is realy a lot going on in this question, I fixed all the errors and I see what went wrong.

The `FormBuilder` interface has one method `Entity()`, witch takes an object and a lambda expression that transforms a `FormSelector` of type a into a `FormSelector` of type b, basically.

```
interface FormBuilder {
Entity: <T1, T2, TResult>(entity: T1, q: (_: FormSelector<T1, Unit>) => FormSelector<T2, TResult>) => Renderer<TResult>
}
```

What went wrong here is that it had the same signatue as the `Select()` method, so this means that the only possible method to and the function chain was `Select()`. Causing `q => q.Select(...).Children(...)` not to compile with a type error.

Also the `Children()` method in `FormSelector` should not have type `U` as second type parameter in the lambda. the type of `q` in `Children` must be an expression that transforms a FormSelector of a nested object from `T` into a `FormSelector` which is a subset from the nested object.

```
interface FormSelector<T, U> {
entity: Pair<T, U>

Select: <K extends keyof T>(this: FormSelector<T, U>, ...properties: K[]) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, Pick<T, K> & U>

Children: <K extends Filter<T, Array<any>>, P extends keyof ArrayType<T[K]>>(
    child: K,
    q: (_: FormSelector<ArrayType<T[K]>, Unit>) => FormSelector<Omit<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>, Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>>
) => FormSelector<Omit<T, K>, U & { [key in K]: Array<Pick<ArrayType<T[K]>, P>> }>
}
```

So changing both expression signatures of `q` in `Entity()` and `Select()` solved the issue for me.

I posted this answer for people who might be interested into building a custom typesafe framework. Also feel free to play arround with the working version in [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=169&ssc=25&pln=164&pc=1#code/PTCqBcEsBtPBPABAWwKbgBYHsAmBnAKFQA8AHLAJ3EQVNUVADs5EBeRAbwF8CizLqtegEEKFAIbwAKvDoAeKQD42iKYhLhUjfIlET4cyIwBmqCg2UB+BogBciRqgBuZgNy8S5KjVn0AYjCaFAoANIgAwljacJBRyuwcBIjJiCCIAMroiOLQ0D50eDQY4tTIJQDGGEX0kdFQUTRY1YhOOQCu9FjGzcaQqNA4iAAUkAB0qKMO4mj2AESM06izAJRJKWkAotB49DuCGPRCjQ7OZmvJANoA0ohGiADWqPBdqgC69lLXr+rEmtqFtRwMQa1hu9kcLnMBC4F0ez26Um+aUy0FQ5XAhRyeUwh18hReWOacMKJHKqFI1GMlBOkI8-G8qOopEg5XuAHlHCpQogbhotDo4S8lEMtFAEB8wqQKFhSHh7DdlvYAAos+7cq7xZSJFKICjoNoURicRAXKUyvDfeyiuDwU3S2XfLjZQoq1nqxTQuleaiMxDM1kAWXEjCQ7HVPz+AqeQsUIsYYvgEr99rlPIur2WbC15z14ANRrNstGepwbTJQyGeEl9szrGUlbtMu+7GtCEbpFeYTwmbC3GdiFdaqkYQ1qx4XoEiF9WGQcA59DDw55Ef5hUFCNjrcTqmrMvlisQbNn4HdWc450Q5SieGoHBNhfeiBw-XQqBwYVGn8cAHd0uASqgTotvGNoXrm+YnL+-6aJ6BBpAASqgxjiOi1KYJAhRGOATTiIgUT9EYZyeJO07HkGIZckuvK-KuDzRhucYJkmhaplc6YHkecCnnW546r6ep4G00DUMBCb9pxJ5UR6OosaMVIUBsKEYEMhZntqOopAJQkiXhx7zkMWnCbupD9m0jD3IwWDfka4hrvRh7Hu6ma2Q5XFSReXCrDq4GGrqqCCcJsHEd4V6MDeiAAJLPiBCAADLTAARjguGLrGtb1sQHzpYgxC8FhZjIWSA7iJAFAyPIS6gNmOoBBQN4ShemShTg9igLB+UUIV9BKiVFBsnQEj1GF3JVbxKRlKQ9gKIhAXgGEoAzdpsboamPWlSNihhMY9hDAA+llZ5SItRmIAA5jt+0MNlC3+dp2VrcER23SdN2zdJ43iKQsVIeAU1PW9QwrcqvUbVtF0HTx-13WeD3Tc9c0WBeE3wZAp0YL9iByK9S2AxgGHA+tlWbWd4NXWe2PCfdIOVcd4AeuOwWCL4xWE-N8Qs2VvgbYgABkHP9WYJSxMNRMTiF17UA9lFs0MvR1RjS47M1rUHrDRNnkM6nJLV9WIHLN4hI1aJRC1iBKybhs6hN9jGGZ6LC5jUMvbTy146t1Ns2DwyXVI2VOwj53eyr5O06r1O0-NLtaxpPlGg9su4xhow6+AyxhKdid4KMTUm8sXkpFwlsfV9P023bQ2Oy7mcE49nt66TvuHaHNdw7NbNjRpfl5r5K2jBNsthFFW7xcgSXiEMeceUXyTI6j6Nl4w9sNJjFN09XHOgyTQdkzxq9h6zDAux3Mf6j3bt959QxDzF8Aj2PE-p-nyQ8J5vBwcAqgHIgfiUMgABCbQYDPnMMYCQaBvyUHuAQDqXVv6-wAUAswx8Ng3z+gARjCFIAATJgquW4PgYMQAAR1Jj-CgyAURomwo9QhTA4CKGymQihL5UKPRwaoF22VELaDMGYVuS0gr0h9FkJhCCBhmHsKIwB4jzDsE1heFBTE9blwdgoQh2DcHw03Kg1QhCSHbyYZQ1haj5rMDpow3+RjqEKHYf7Bh9huHAL4XY4+3lT5GjvMlf89giFXzMZAHIhiWHUMYjaPO4wb7Z2NtoRAPAdQv1WNA+MBUUL+EscEyg3No74I3qLI2qJ0RTWopGOy8JVCu3xnA8hVjMlEw-J+QsZgoD+XlOxM8QSCnWIku6MIg5Tx8yqrwHU4Q8YDD1IwIpK5-jf0CM4sIehJByGDPARQxMlRTKjGUhZ0guafCuK8VZQwLw6kqEA+U08NL6L2pI9JnTMnbPKqgBQXxiZ0PMe025VDMndIebsl5vS1mqjkL8iq-yByrIvBY6pGTgjdKkvNXmxpYRPFuEafZ9htlyD6SCp5eyDkAuUFwemvBfQRX8YEz5rDKKbiyjc6Fdza4MDMZqYY2SdHx1QL2Tyht8lUIXkvI0chim0XXOU9eHSvmMu4MTT8oxGlUD6KxdidLmEMrkHCkcgK3RSWqp3LuEEJWsMzhEhMF9SBHL1RpYw4UeIzjgOReAssDbJhlE0xVadjl6rwDEnimtECyu9e+f1DTVQOuNVuZOpVnXyuad2WJT8NKT3iTy4ZoycDjP5RXIVGzCgBGEnM3QYhFnLNWb0nNdEtlFp2aC-ZhzPXJFOQMc59biGkMpdYnFzza2mPoVC1Vkr1WOU7XitZWq1TDrBUqCFOoDyGq6Y5eFnAnR8zvMipAdx0WFv0FioFE7u3gsJbqzuscqn9qNb3CN-cW06mtSJZQdrwD6VvWERtOAPWWp1IGjWd4A3aDCBcV9j4Li+LJTECl9LJXhsiSnADabvguT3Qc8JEac7aEdM5TEIYW1JoLtCRJvo53UkXDLVALciazvbbU9uvq2VKM5UMlIVjM2qOFdM0VwoganpqYyqq9S5X2jdS0tMGYVXccHW5TVvSgVSURaNaObju5GkIxQKDpqr0fpSLes8D6w3PpdQNWN76NNmx9fWH9n5A18f9PcMNF7oNRoRjG918bsMJsLgx5IIygEZuUYvLNrGdB5qCNyTFJa1nltFYhutlrX3NstVcy6yngVVseV2-FTLe0fIg8Yn5KW-n7qnVJt0UWCWQtEzC8TklJM2BXSaOEqKeSPkxdivLNb0tTsPa4zS7iuMwtUzaM1FrjNadtXpRwTqEavqMxpr9NHg2jEsyaQD9hgN+LA9AZT-WECRvlrBoB8HChReQ5E1DOB0P9mWa5jyeG35pCkG7RA34YB5ASvQAS5AwqQASqiPW1JxnAKMKdHov8X3BkQK9v0LlsLZD8ihagV5kAfdFEkoIsDHG8Mekep8JRxAfFgsiaYpAftXmfIgAgRw-xtGijpaOkBTaMDaKPM4OoFgzDNuACggOLykBKqbBKWAsComDBeU6-IJGIAAOTIAl4gAAPpLpwEuLxXgNDsVMkRVeoHTLBI4Gu6oLmPqz0j7POeMFOsr3Axubym-N5+vMOBZBYCwuCRnr2KCwVCuFAAIkhcQ2lKfU-sAH0UKhaemwwSLsXFA5jIFmBco39gJcS4uTzunNscg7AuSr-XqYLgtvk3qknxuJde42AANQAGx-2T2T4zUw2cS+EDgVoi83yIC9zjhKtl-LJ+vSkG8VPHfO8QFgltcSUivFgr6ZA8AmEqCkYgigoxFE2iGD75C-v7eiguUQs8RComdKGBLo3NeJei54RQCXywD9UKP6nnAV+LyjC82MrQR-s9q5r7vni++rFH5P9fn-hLgPg7uQFhFfqsIkp7oLhMNAFgBnDPkwqMF4uIKsEAA)

Comment: Also there is still a small bug in the code in the playground, when inlcuding a list ype with children the values are undefined. this is because when Select is called on an array it treats like a regular object without itterating over the entries. So I will probably extend the framework to only work with lists or arrays.